# How can I implement graph database with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, graph

I want to implement connection as friends of friends using MySQL

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE user (
 id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
 ....
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE friendof (
  user_a_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  user_b_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_a_id, user_b_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_a_id) REFERENCES user(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_b_id) REFERENCES user(id),
  KEY reverseLookup (user_b_id),
  KEY lookup (user_a_id),
);
```

Was that really so hard?

Comment: maybe he meant how to traverse such tables? running DFS on mySql can be tricky

Comment: add engine=innodb (now default in 5.5) and drop key lookup(user_a_id) and you'll be well sorted !